# Is there a way in the AtTask API to get every project where a custom field is not null?

Tags: rest, attask

I want to search for a project where a custom field is not null. Something like this:

```
GET /attask/api/project/search?status_mod=notnull&&DE:Custom Field_mod=notnull
```

I see it's working for normal fields, but when I try this for a custom field it's crashing, when I extend the field with `_mod`.

Comment: Perhaps not particularly relevant here, but for the next question you're asking, please note that statements such as _"it's crashing"_ aren't particularly meaningful to readers of your question. Instead of saying that, please describe exactly what happens (and what you expected to happen instead).

Comment: The _mod should work with notnull for custom fields. I suggest entering a ticket into the help desk with the exact call you are trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late on this but have you tried something like this?

GET /attask/api/project/search?status_mod=notnull&DE:Custom Field=0&DE:Custom Field_mod=notnull?

You usually need to give it a value before you try to modify the value from what i understand.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I immediately tried, this is the response:


    {"error":{"class":"com.attask.common.InvalidParameterException","message":"Invalid Parameter: Search Parameter value \"DE:Custom Field ID_mod\"","title":null,"msgKey":"exception.attask","attributes":[""],"code":0}}

Comment: the M in _mod needs to be capitalized. to _Mod=notnull

Answer (score 0):

You can use below request url

GET attask/api/project/search?apiKey=xxxxx&status_mod=notnull&categoryID_Mod=notnull

It will return all project which contains custom_fields(part of category)

GET attask/api/project/search?apiKey=xxxxx&status_mod=notnull&DE:Custom Field_Mod=notnull

you need to use  "_Mod" (M in caps) with any custom_field which should be present on Workfront.